# How to send an .ipa file through email from Bitrise?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, bitrise

I'm using Bitrise to build a .ipa file signed to upload it to the App Store. But, I don't want to deploy it directly to the App Store from Bitrise. Instead of that, I want to send the .ipa file through an email to my customer and he will be incharge to upload it to his account manually.

I have the Mailgun Step on Bitrise, is it possible to send the .ipa file as an attachment?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You will need to zip up the file before attaching it to the File attachments environment variable for the step. This should be a path to the IPA which can be determined by looking at previous steps.